# Checking if IP address is mapped to localhost

Tags: windows, networking, localhost, ip-address

Generally 99.9 % of time `localhost` is pointing to `127.0.0.1` in Windows machine
but for rest 0.1% ...?
How to check IP address mapped to localhost?

1. I did not find anything on hosts file.
2. When I am pinging `localhost` that also not returning anything.
   [image: ping localhost]

Comment: For IPv4, anything in the `127.0.0.0/8` network is a loopback (localhost) address. For IPv6, there is one loopback address: `::1`. The address you see is the localhost address for IPv6. You cannot use the IPv4 `127.0.0.1` address in IPv6.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "not returning anything"? Your screenshot shows that localhost maps to ::1 and that is a [valid IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Local_addresses). Use `ping -4 localhost` if you want to limit yourself to IPv4.

From a programming standpoint you would call something like [`getaddrinfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the list of address**es** that localhost maps to...